# sbt idiomatic way to add settings

Tags: scala, sbt

I see this a lot in open source sbt projects:

```
lazy val project = Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file("."),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    ...
  )
)
```

We adopted this convention for our in-house projects also. However today i tried sbt-ensime with a project like this and running "gen-ensime" gave me an error:

```
[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.7' to configuration 'ensime-internal' of module ... because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

The suggested fix is here: https://github.com/ensime/ensime-sbt/issues/145

It suggests i change my project to:

```
lazy val project = Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file(".")
).settings(Seq(
  ...
)
```

My question is: is this suggested way of defining the project idiomatic and preferred for sbt? Do i lose anything by using this (in particular, are the defaultSettings still added to my project)?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like difference between those two that

```scala
.settings(Seq(...))
```

is append your sequence to 'settings' in project, but

```scala
Project(settings = ...)
```

just writing settings without saving old values.

Thereby it looks like .settings() is more safe approach.

In general .settings() more idiomatic now, because some sbt plugins may 
try to modify settings at Project construction.

Few snippets from sbt sources:

```scala
/**
 * The explicitly defined sequence of settings that configure this project.
 * These do not include the automatically appended settings as configured by `auto`.
 */
def settings: Seq[Setting[_]]

/** Appends settings to the current settings sequence for this project. */
def settings(ss: Def.SettingsDefinition*): Project = copy(settings = (settings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]]) ++ Def.settings(ss: _*))

// TODO: Modify default settings to be the core settings, and automatically add the IvyModule + JvmPlugins.
def apply(id: String, base: File, aggregate: => Seq[ProjectReference] = Nil, dependencies: => Seq[ClasspathDep[ProjectReference]] = Nil,
    delegates: => Seq[ProjectReference] = Nil, settings: => Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Nil, configurations: Seq[Configuration] = Nil,
    auto: AddSettings = AddSettings.allDefaults): Project =
    unresolved(id, base, aggregate, dependencies, delegates, settings, configurations, auto, Plugins.empty, Nil) // Note: JvmModule/IvyModule auto included...

def copy(id: String = id, base: File = base, aggregate: => Seq[ProjectReference] = aggregate, dependencies: => Seq[ClasspathDep[ProjectReference]] = dependencies,
    delegates: => Seq[ProjectReference] = delegates, settings: => Seq[Setting[_]] = settings, configurations: Seq[Configuration] = configurations,
    auto: AddSettings = auto): Project =
    unresolved(id, base, aggregate = aggregate, dependencies = dependencies, delegates = delegates, settings, configurations, auto, plugins, autoPlugins)
```

Comment: looks like ```Project(settings = ...)``` is deprecated now, see https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2524#issuecomment-202749479

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches have right to exist. Passing settings in constructor `Project(settings = ...)` came from old times, when SBT configurations was static. As *autoplugin* advents, configuration conceptions switched to mutable paradigm, and `Project().settings(...)` is compatible with it.

I prefer the first approach, as it is more explicit.

---

```
[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        Cannot add dependency 'org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.7' to configuration 'ensime-internal' of module ...
        because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

The error could be fixed in two ways:

### Project-level way

You may explicitly add ensime settings in the project definition

```
import org.ensime.EnsimePlugin

lazy val project = Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file("."),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ EnsimePlugin.projectSettings ++ Seq(
    ...
  )
)
```

### Global-level way

Or you could add ensime settings to default project settings in global level in `~/.sbt/SBT_VERSION/global.sbt`

```
import org.ensime.EnsimePlugin

EnsimePlugin.projectSettings
```

Comment: Trying the "Global-level way" I get a "object ensime is not a member of package org" error.  Is there something else I need to add to my global config to make this work?

Comment: You need to enable the ensime plugin of cource. Add `addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "1.0.0")` to `~/.sbt/SBT_VERSION/plugins/build.sbt`